# RQDA installing using Rstudio and R version 4.3.2

Tags: r

I'm having a problem installing RQDA. I used this code in R

A little help. Thanks.

I used this code

install. Packages(c("RGtk2","igraph","plogr","bit","RSQLite","cairoDevice"),depen=T)

then

library("RGtk2")

got an error: RGtk2 no installed

I cannot proceed in installing RQDA

Comment: What is the full output of `install.packages("RGtk2")`?

Comment: install.packages("gwidgetsRGtk2","RGtk2")
Warning in install.packages("gwidgetsRGtk2", "RGtk2") :
  'lib = "RGtk2"' is not writable
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘gwidgetsRGtk2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: I'm using cherry blossom version of R, and "RGtk2", "gwidgetsRGtk2", and "RQDA" do not install in my version. What will I do? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to install two package, it should be `install.packages(c("gwidgetsRGtk2","RGtk2"))`, not what you typed; but I asked what was the output when you just ran `install.packages("RGtk2")`